# Stack Trace in Goto Statements

Tags: c++, stack-trace, goto

Suppose I use a goto statement in a recursive call, which redirects to my main function, what will happen to the information present in the stack memory?
Suppose it is something like this,

```
void recurse(int n){
    if(n==0) goto p;
    ....
}
int main(){
    recurse(100);
    p:;
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the answer, goto statements cannot exactly be used outside the scope of the function, so the primary cause of doubt is wrong.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non existing things, like fairies, unicorns, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because `goto` can only go to a label in the same function.

> #### C++11 6.6.4 The `goto` statement
>
> The `goto` statement unconditionally transfers control to the statement labeled by the identifier. The identifier shall be a label (6.1) located in the current function.

Comment: Oh I see, since we cannot use `goto` statements this way, but we can sure use statements like `setjmp`. I was wondering how the control flow happens and the stack trace looks like in such a case.

Comment: @Sushant Then perhaps you should ask a new question with a minimal example using `setjmp` and `longjmp` to describe your question?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion anyway. I wasn't aware that goto labels cannot be used outside the scope of the function.